# SQL query function in Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sqlite

I have a series of attributes in the Excel sheet and I build up a series of a SELECT statements using Excel formulas, which I then just pass into my SQL query function.

So something like this

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnString);
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQLQuery,ConString);                
conn.Open();
// execute query code
// populate result object
conn.Dispose();
// return results
```

Given that I'm performing a series of SQL queries on the same database, should the `conn.Open()` and `conn.Dispose()` methods be part of the SQL query function itself?

How much overhead is there to opening and closing connections for each query?

Or would it better practice to simply open one connection (via a different method), then run all the queries, and finally close the connection? Is there any risk of the latter? i.e. Excel sheet crashing with the connection open, etc?

Am just looking for some ideas on best practices, etc.

Comment: The connections will come from the connection pool, so there is little overhead in creating and disposing them.  I would suggest that you put your connection, commad, and reader (if you use one) into `using` statements so you don't have to call `Dispose` manually and it will get called even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've decided to put them into a `finally` block, which has working quite nicely.